# IPhone App Memory Keeps Growing

Tags: iphone, ios, memory-management, xcode-instruments, allocation

I was all ready to submit my first app to the app store.  Checked for leaks, tested on devices, the works.  I wanted to make sure my memory was under control so I ran allocations, and, alas, nothing was under control.

I've test multiple areas of my app, but I focused on a couple big areas where continued use by the user could make the memory get out of control very easily.  To me the information from Allocations/Heapshots is hard to read, so I'm hoping someone out there can Rosetta Stone this output for me.

I'll try to give as much detail as possible, and if it's not enough, just yell, and I'll write more.

App starts at a Menu.  Clicking a button brings up a view, via presentModalViewController.  The view comes up and in the background a database is opened and a random row is selected and stored. So the cycle of: Click on Main Menu->Open View->Close View causes my memory to grow at a rate of 10KB-25KB every time.

Some thoughts:

- Some parts of my view are created via IB, with some of the buttons
  being custom .png files.  I read that an earlier build had trouble
  releasing and reallocating these resources which caused memory leaks.
- I've been using button.layer.borderWidth/borderColor/cornerRadius/backgroundColor with some of my buttons that were originally created in IB.  Is this a no-no? (Removing them does help a bit, but the problem still shows up).

For those curious, this is the call stack for the biggest of the heap growth:

```
0 libSystem.B.dylib calloc
1 CoreGraphics CGGlyphBitmapCreate
2 CoreGraphics CGFontCreateGlyphBitmap8
3 CoreGraphics CGFontCreateGlyphBitmap
4 CoreGraphics CGGlyphLockLockGlyphBitmaps
5 libRIP.A.dylib ripc_DrawGlyphs
6 CoreGraphics draw_glyphs
7 CoreGraphics CGContextShowGlyphsWithAdvances
8 WebCore WebCore::showGlyphsWithAdvances(WebCore::FloatPoint const&, WebCore::SimpleFontData const*, CGContext*, unsigned short const*, CGSize const*, unsigned long)
9 WebCore WebCore::Font::drawGlyphs(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::SimpleFontData const*, WebCore::GlyphBuffer const&, int, int, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, bool) const
10 WebCore WebCore::Font::drawSimpleText(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::TextRun const&, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, int, int) const
11 WebCore WebCore::Font::drawText(WebCore::GraphicsContext*, WebCore::TextRun const&, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, int, int) const
12 WebKit drawAtPoint(unsigned short const*, int, WebCore::FloatPoint const&, WebCore::Font const&, WebCore::GraphicsContext*, bool, WebCore::BidiStatus*, int)
13 WebKit -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:ellipsis:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:drawUnderline:]
14 WebKit -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:ellipsis:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:measureOnly:renderedStringOut:]
15 WebKit -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) __web_drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:ellipsis:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:measureOnly:]
16 WebKit -[NSString(WebStringDrawing) _web_drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:ellipsis:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:]
17 UIKit -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:lineBreakMode:letterSpacing:includeEmoji:]
18 UIKit -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:fontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:includeEmoji:]
19 UIKit -[NSString(UIStringDrawing) drawAtPoint:forWidth:withFont:fontSize:lineBreakMode:baselineAdjustment:]
20 UIKit -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:]
21 UIKit -[UILabel drawTextInRect:]
22 UIKit -[UILabel drawRect:]
23 UIKit -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) drawLayer:inContext:]
24 QuartzCore -[CALayer drawInContext:]
25 QuartzCore backing_callback(CGContext*, void*)
26 QuartzCore CABackingStoreUpdate_
27 QuartzCore CA::Layer::display_()
28 QuartzCore -[CALayer _display]
29 QuartzCore CA::Layer::display()
30 QuartzCore -[CALayer display]
31 QuartzCore CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
32 QuartzCore CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*)
33 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::commit()
34 QuartzCore CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*)
35 CoreFoundation __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__
36 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopDoObservers
37 CoreFoundation __CFRunLoopRun
38 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunSpecific
39 CoreFoundation CFRunLoopRunInMode
40 GraphicsServices GSEventRunModal
41 GraphicsServices GSEventRun
42 UIKit UIApplicationMain
43 GRE Words main /Users/admin/Dropbox/GRE Words/main.m:14
44 GRE Words start
```

If you think bits of code will help, please let me know.  I felt like I was moving forward and this has been pretty disheartening.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Heapshot to find memory creap, see: [bbum blog](http://www.friday.com/bbum/2010/10/17/when-is-a-leak-not-a-leak-using-heapshot-analysis-to-find-undesirable-memory-growth/)

Basically there method is to run Instruments allocate tool, take a heapshot, run an intuition of your code and another heapshot repeating 3 or 4 times. This will indicate memory that is allocated and not released during the iterations.

To figure out the results disclose to see the individual allocations.

If you need to see where retains, releases and autoreleases occur for an object use instruments:

Run in instruments, in Allocations set "Record reference counts" on on (you have to stop recording to set the option). Cause the picker to run, stop recording, search for there ivar (datePickerView), drill down and you will be able to see where all retains, releases and autoreleases occurred.

[image]

I have used this many times and it really helped, good luck.

Comment: Right, that's what I did (which is how I came up with the numbers that I mention above).  I can't decipher any of it though, everything seems to be internal and not pointing directly to any of my methods.